# how to get value of checked box where values are dynamiclly in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***this html code***

in this code value of ng-repeat coming dynamically feedback value is training,nature of work, etc i have to fetch value checked radio button in five option poor,average,good,excellent

```
<form name="exitEmp" ng-submit=submit(exitEmp) novalidate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <br />
            <th>Factors</th>
            <th>Poor</th>
            <th>Average</th>
            <th>Above Average</th>
            <th>Good</th>
            <th>Excellent</th>
        </tr>
        <div>
            <div>
                <tr ng-if="feedback.qtype=='radio'" ng-repeat="feedback in empratingquestion" >
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>{{feedback.question}}</td>
                    <td><input type="radio"  name="feedback" ng-checked="feedback.checked"  ng-change="handleRadioClick(feedback)"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio"></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your html, cause it has some problems (eg: div's in tables, more div closing tags than div opening tags, no closing of the form tag, <br /> in table row elements)

Comment: yeh this is html actually i have send process which i am trying to implement have u any idea about this

Comment: With that ([invalid](https://jsfiddle.net/tfwbem40/), look at the red as well as the invalid placement of the `<br />`) HTML JavaScript will work unpredictably if at all. So first: fix the HTML in order to create a reliable DOM structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small demo that could help you finding a solution for your problem. To understand the problem in a bit deeper way, you have to know how radio buttons actually allow you to select only 1 of them per row

Radio buttons work on the principle that only one value can be selected for a certain name. They are grouped in such a way, as such one important part of your code change should be that you give your radiobuttons a unique name per question, in my example, I name the radio buttons based on the current question, like so:

```
    <td><input type="radio" name="{{evaluation.id}}-evaluation" value="-1" ng-model="evaluation.value" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="{{evaluation.id}}-evaluation" value="0" ng-model="evaluation.value" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="{{evaluation.id}}-evaluation" value="1" ng-model="evaluation.value" /></td>
```

As you can see, they have the same name for this question (based on their id), and 3 different values that are linked to a property on the question

I don't  have to set the checked value per radio button, it will be checked when it's value equals to the value of the input element (eg: -1 for Bad, 0 for Neutral and 1 for Good)

As such, there is no need for a clickhandler on the elements, you just change the value of the current question.

Furthermore, it's important that your HTML layout is a valid one. Your current code has div elements where they shouldn't be allowed, and you have more closing than opening tags. You could check to use the code I used and alter your html in a similar  way.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('feedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  var evaluationQuestions = [
   {
     id: 'quality',
     question: 'Quality',
      value: 0
    },
    {
     id: 'overview',
     question: 'Overview',
      value: 0
    },
    {
     id: 'content',
      question: 'Content',
      value: 0
    }
  ];
  
  function showEvaluationResults() {
   console.log( $scope.evaluationQuestions.map(function( item ) {
     return item.question + ' has value ' + item.value;
    }).join('\r\n') )
  }
  
  function reset() {
   $scope.evaluationQuestions.forEach(function(item) {
     item.value = 0;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.evaluationQuestions = evaluationQuestions;
  $scope.showEvaluationResults = showEvaluationResults;
  $scope.reset = reset;
  
  return $scope;
}]);
```

```css
.separator {
  width: 10px;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0 0;
}
table td, table th {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
table th {
  font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="feedbackController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th class="separator"></th>
        <th>Bad</th>
        <th>Neutral</th>
        <th>Good</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="evaluation in evaluationQuestions">
        <td>{{ evaluation.question }}</td>
        <td class="separator"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="{{evaluation.id}}-evaluation" value="-1" ng-model="evaluation.value" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="{{evaluation.id}}-evaluation" value="0" ng-model="evaluation.value" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="{{evaluation.id}}-evaluation" value="1" ng-model="evaluation.value" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" ng-click="showEvaluationResults()">
      Show current results
    </button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="reset()">
      Reset
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```